# weak property calls objc_storeStrong

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class called Panel which contains a weak property like this:

@property (nonatomic, weak) Dialog *container;

In Instruments, I can see that setContainer method ends up calling objc_storeStrong.

Is this correct? I thought that weak properties did not increase the retain count.

My init method is as follows:

```
- (id) initWithContainer:(Dialog *)pContainer{
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        self.container = pContainer;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Please advice.
Thanks,

Comment: Now that can't be good.  Are you absolutely sure that this is what's calling objc_storeStrong?  Because it would seem that your situation contradicts the [CLANG ARC Reference](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#runtime.objc_storeStrong).

Comment: I am using the simulator. I have checked and made sure ARC is turned on in the project settings and that the target is using Apple LLVM compiler 3.1. I am pretty sure I can see in instruments the following callstack pointing to an extra retain for Dialog:                        4 [DialogPanel initWithContainer:]
3 [DialogPanel setContainer:]
2 libobjc.A.dylib objc_storeStrong
1 libobjc.A.dylib objc_retain
0 CoreFoundation -[NSObject retain]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you all for your help while debugging this issue. I greatly appreciate it. My knowledge was/is correct, and weak does not increase the retain count. Unfortunately, I have spent hours debugging this issue that ended up being Instruments picking up an old version of the App that was built without the property being made weak. I don't know how this happened because I was launching instruments from within Xcode project, did a clean, etc... but something was wrong because when I launched instruments it would ask me for the instrument twice, not once, and then instead of launching the app automatically, I would have to start it manually by picking the target (which was wrong, because it usually launches the app automatically.) I resolved the issue by quitting instruments, Xcode and the simulator and restarting again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting an `objc_storeStrong` message sent, but not to the container property.  It's sent to your arg because local variables are automatically passed strong and retained (if weak isn't specified), and retained on assignment.  When your method returns, arc releases the arg for you automagically.

Comment: I am actually seeing two retains and one release. That is why I asked about the extra retain which seems to be in setContainer. The argument retain/release is happening in OK (in pair). 
5 0xae3a600 Dialog Retain 2 00:11.258.360 0  -[DialogPanel initWithContainer]
6 0xae3a600 Dialog Retain 3 00:11.258.450 0  -[DialogPanel setContainer:]
7 0xae3a600 Dialog Release 2 00:11.258.453 0  -[DialogPanel initWithContainer]

Comment: Of course.  Arc retains method arguments, then releases them when the function returns.

Comment: But why am I seeing a second retain for the setContainer method call? This is increasing the overall retain count and the object never gets deallocated.

Comment: Because setters retain their args... You do understand basic MRC storage rules, right?  And that weak doesn't mean the object can't recieve a retain message?

Comment: Never mind, I think I am having a workspace issue. Instruments is picking up the app from another workspace even though I am profiling from the correct workspace... ARGGGG!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Kudos for using instruments.

First, you should use the iVar directly in init/dealloc.

Second, do you synthesize it yourself, or implement the setter yourself?

Also, are you running debug or release-optimized code?

Now, the explanation of why I answered your question with more questions.

If you synthesize it yourself (i.e., declaring your own instance variable, you also have to declare that as __weak.  If you let the compiler do it, it will handle it properly.

Now, you are obviously using ARC.  So, the compiler is going to automatically add code to perform manual reference counting (some of which may be removed later by the optimizer).  Now, I don't pretend to be an expert on what the compiler creates automatically, but it's going to be very close to the following.

Take a basic assignment for example...

```
- (void)setContainer(Container*)container {
    _container = container;
}
```

When the compiler is done injecting its ARC code, this will look something like (assuming _container is NOT declared __weak)...

```
// Converted by ARC -- so it's MRC
- (void)setContainer(Container*)container {
    [container retain];
    Container *oldContainer = _container;
    _container = [container retain];
    [oldContainer release];
    [container release];
}
```

Now, let's take that a step further, assuming _container is __weak, we get something like this...

```
- (void)setContainer(Container*)container {
    [container retain]
    Container *oldContainer = [_container retain];
    objc_storeWeak(&_container, container);
    [oldContainer release];
    [container release];
}
```

Now, objc_storeStrong is the sequence for assigning to a strong variable, so it is obvious where that would fit in the above code.

Also, note, the compiler is ver judicious in how it adds code.  The optimizer is very aggressive, and can remove most retain/release pairs that are obviously unneeded.  So, in most cases, you will see different semantics for retain/release in functions, depending on whether you build debug or release.

In general, though, you must expect to get at least a retain on any parameter, unless specified as __unsafe_unretained.